# Ubuntu 22.04 Black Screen after Login after clean install

Tags: boot, login, 22.04

Recently upgraded to 22.04 on my desktop, it was running fine until the other morning. At the login screen I put in my password and the screen just goes black. I've tried leaving it for a few minutes to see if it was just being slow but nope.

Steps taken since then:

- change from xorg to Wayland and the reverse
- Tried reinstalling the login manager
- Checked to see if the issue was the xorg config
- Disconnected other drives (dual boot with windows and a storage hard drive)
- Tried updating/reinstalling graphics card drivers

I can get into a TTY shell using `crtl+alt+F5`and everything seems ok. The windows side of the machine is working fine.

Eventually I resolved to just doing full erase and clean install. This didn't work either so I'm fresh out of ideas.

Any help would be very much appreciated :)

Comment: I have your problem too, but I can't fix it with bellow answer

Answer (score 4):

This happened to me as well on both my old (10 years) Ubuntu machines. It *seems* that is a common problem with Ubuntu 22.04, the 5.15.0-52 kernel and some older machines, but don't quote me on that.

Some machines are affected at the login while others when waking from suspend. [Upgrading to the 5.18.0 kernel seems to fix the issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1970957) (check the last message).

In the meantime, I managed to get my PCs back to work by disabling the GPU drivers via `nomodeset`, here's how to do that:

First, log into a TTY shell and access the GRUB configuration file

```bash
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

and replace the value of `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX`: from empty string `""` to `"nomodeset"` as follows

```bash
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

to

```bash
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nomodeset"
```

then save the file and update GRUB with

```bash
sudo update-grub
```

Finally, reboot and you should be able to login.

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me. I have Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS with Kernel 6.2.0