# Ubuntu 23.04 Black screen with a solid cursor after boot

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel, 22.04, 23.04

I've been facing an issue with my Lenovo Thinkpad P14s where I see a blank screen after booting into ubuntu 23.04. After boot I don't even see the login screen instead I just see a blank screen with a **non blinking underscore** on the top right, and I'm not even able to get to a TTY terminal by pressing `ctrl+alt+f3/4/5`. The only way to get to a TTY terminal I found was to go into ubuntu recovery mode.

I found multiple similar questions here with the same problem but none of the solutions seems to be working for me. One of the question [Ubuntu 22.04 Black Screen after Login after clean install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1437664/ubuntu-22-04-black-screen-after-login-after-clean-install) which does partially work, it mentions a work around and a permanent fix. The workaround is to set `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nomodeset"` in file `/etc/default/grub` which allows me to login fine, but then my external monitor connected via the HDMI port stops working. And the permanent fix mentioned in above question was to upgrade the kernel verison, but I've 6.2.0-32-generic kernel installed already and it doesn't look like there is an update avaialble for it.

I believe the issue first started appearing after I let an available update to be installed for the kernel from 5.19.0-50-generic to 6.2.0-31-generic, after that I manually updated to ubuntu 23.04 from 22.04 (which also updated the kernal to 6.2.0-32-generic) in the hope that it would fix this issue but the issue still persists.